# Laravel, You need to specify a file path to store the seed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have copy my new Laravel project in my new directory. But my project is not included with "vendor" directory. So I run command:

```
composer install
```

And everything run smoothly vendor direcotory created and filled in with packages.

Then I refresh my web page, suddenly I get an error. But usually I do like this without error.

> **You need to specify a file path to store the seed**

The error was in file D:\www\laravel\myproject\vendor\symfony\security\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Util\SecureRandom.php

```
...    
                $this->logger->info('OpenSSL did not produce a secure random number.');
            }
        }

    // initialize seed
    if (null === $this->seed) {
        if (null === $this->seedFile) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('You need to specify a file path to store the seed.');
            }
...
```

When I check my Laravel version, my Laravel updated to version 4.1.28.

I use wamp for Windows 7 64bit.

Is there a something that I missed? Thank you.

Comment: You should provide that as an answer instead of adding solution to the end of the question.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange: we prefer that questions are not marked as `[solved]` here, since acceptance is a better way to mark them as such.

Answer (score 5):

The answer by @FathurRohman (moved out of the question):

I'am searching another solution and I found it here http://laravel.io/forum/04-18-2014-you-need-to-specify-a-file-path-to-store-the-seed

This caused i am not enable my php_openssl in my php.ini. When I enable this extension, make sure that **openSSL support** is enable, not **Native OpenSSL support**

Answer (score 1):

Enabling openSSL in php modules corrects this error.
in file (for windows) "C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin\php.ini"
enable the "extension=php_openssl.dll" by deleting ;

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me and it was beacuse my php version was to low.  I was using 5.3.1 and the min was 5.3.7.   All was OK when I upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

i was also getting same error when i try to access my project like

```
localhost/myproject/
```

Let me tell you my case:-
1.)i was install my laravel project on lamp server and after some time i move project to xampp server.

2.)i try to access project and then i get this **SEXY** error :). Then i go to my php.ini file in (xampp server) and change setting of **OpenSSL support** to **enable** and i get rid off  that error.

3.)When i **echo phpinfo()** i get  o/p like:-

```
openssl  
OpenSSL support             -->**enabled**  
OpenSSL Library Version     -->**OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013**  
OpenSSL Header Version      -->**OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013**
```

that's all i do for enjoy  this :)
oohh my laravel version is **4.1**

Answer (score 0):

You just need to go to php.ini find openSSL and enable it. then restart wamp all servcies